# With what odds and payout should I play a game?

Tags: probability, gambling

- Should I play a game that returns $1.5\times$ my wager if I win and returns nothing if I lose at exactly $50-50$ odds?
- How does this change if my odds are $>50\%?$
- How does this change if the payout is greater?

I'm trying to figure out which variable matters, if not both.

I've tried justifying my intuition (always play if $>50\%$ odds, regardless of payout) with references around, but most of the material around applies to gambling, where the payout is $2.0\times$.

I'd like a formula that accepts both of these variables as input and simply states "yes" or "no" ($1$ or $0$, any boolean, etc).

Comment: Calculate the **expected value** of winnings and see if it's negative or positive. If $p$ is the probability of winning, you can calculate is like so:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\text{winnings}] = p\cdot (\text{outcome when you win}) + (1-p) \cdot (\text{outcome when you lose})
$$

Comment: As a numerical example, you can set $p=\frac{1}{2}$. When you win, you can get 1.5x your wager (**on top** of your original wager, so now you actually have 2.5 times the wager), so outcome when you win is $1.5$. But when you lose, you lose all of the wager so the outcome in that case is $-1$. In this case, the expected outcome is
$$
\frac{1}{2} \cdot (1.5) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (-1) = 0.25 > 0
$$
so it's worth playing. But if you get only $0.5$ times the wager back (so that you would have 1.5 times the wager after collecting the prize), then the result becomes negative.

Comment: @matti-p Ah, I've mistated the problem (and will fix it above to clarify). In my scenario, in the winning case, you walk away with simply 1.5x your wager, not 2.5x. According to this formula, I'd be in the red.

Comment: Thanks for answering my follow-up comment with your edit.

Comment: Yeah, well now you have the formula and you can use it for all cases. Just plug in whichever numbers you want and you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your wager is $x$ and, the probability that you win is $p$. Suppose the game returns your wager $k$ times if you win, and nothing if you lose (and I assume, that you pay your initial wager in both cases). Then your expected surplus will be:

$$(k-1)px - (1-p)x = (kp - 1)x$$

It is positive iff $p \geq \frac{1}{k}$.

Thus, in your particular case ($k = \frac{3}{2}$) the game will be worth playing if and only if your odds are greater than $\frac{2}{3}$